# STO using Ethereum

Tags: tokens, ico, nft

Is anyone here worked on STO using various ERC protocols. Need to get some information about it.

Regards, 
Divansh

Comment: This question does not follow the good format of the questions. I suggest you edit it to be more specific what *questions* you have. StackExchange is not a forum, but Q&A site.

Comment: Hi Mikko, Thanks for your suggestion. Actually i have just started  learning about and want some use cases which have been implemented using  Security Token. And which protocols developers are currently using to build security token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find our security token tools and smart contracts here:

https://github.com/miohtama/sto

My blog posts about the topic:

https://capitalgram.com/posts/what-are-securities-and-security-tokens/

https://capitalgram.com/posts/programming-security-token-smart-contracts/

Hopefully enough to get started.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in "My LinkedIn post about the topic:" link.